# Kafka Connect Offsets range. Get?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

Is it possible to read data for offset range  in kafka using kafka connect sink and stop process automatically?.

I want to read data of 1st 10,000 records using sinkconnector and stop connect process to calculate read timing.

or i want to stop kafka-connect process when there is no data received from kafka topic after certain time.

Comment: Not using connect directly but you could just put the messages in their own topic. Using the console consumer you can consume the first X messages of a topic and pipe that console output to a console producer sending the data to a new topic. Then use this topic for your benchmark?

Comment: i need to check performance in kafka-connect as it does deserialization in converter

Comment: Right, the method above lets you pull out a fixed number of messages to read with the connector. Alternatively you could monitor the worker with JMX and see consumption rate there instead of relying on a timer and known message number.